# in my c# application the other form are set in form.default.show but the other new forms are not setting

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio

forms are set as 'form1.Default.Show()' but the new form are not set. tell me how to do that to show form by setting the new form as form2.default.show()

Comment: ....why [tag:c] tag?? BTW your question is unclear: you must add code and explain better your problem. Take a Look at [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) section.

Comment: Add some code samples, explain your problem in more detailed way.

Answer (score 1):

It appears you want to have some kind of static access to the `Form` by using the `Default` Property?

Inside your Form code behind add this *(note: this is **not** thread safe)*

```
private static Form1 instance;

public static Form1 Default
{
    get
    {
        if (instance == null) {
            instance = new Form1();
            instance.FormClosed += delegate { instance = null; };
        }
        return instance;
    }
}
```

Now you can call the Form like this:

```
Form1.Default.Show();
```

Answer (score 0):

First pic showing error:

[image: first pic]

2nd pic i right coding:

[image: 2nd pic]

Comment: is this an answer?